# How to simply detect updates to firebase in Background with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to figure out. How the observer can simply listen for messages/updates in the background state. For example your text messaging app on your phone will alert you when you have a new message even if your messaging application isn't even open. It seems something so simple.

Code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, let toId = selectedUser?.id else { return }

    let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid).child(toId)

    userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let messageId = snapshot.key

        let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)

        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            print("Update occurred. We have a new message")

        }, withCancel: { (error:Error) -> Void in })
    }, withCancel: { (error:Error) -> Void in }) 

return true
}
```

Comment: Or if anybody can point me to a question the specifically answers this. Thanks

Comment: When you app isn't running in the foreground, most of its regular code isn't running and its network interactions are quickly stopped too. The most common way to send updates to an app in this state is through push notifications, for example through Firebase Cloud Messaging. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40337765, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39011182

Comment: ok thanks! I will look at the links