# Firebase Realtime database observer not working in background mode

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat app with the help of Firebase Realtime Database. When any user send me msg it should update delivery report like WhatsApp, so i update delivery node on particular msgid.

So i have implement silent push notification for this, whenever msg receive in `didRecieveRemoteNotification` delegate the background task invoke. My code here.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                       didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                       fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult)
                         -> Void) {

//extracting here pathStr and chatId from payload

    if (backgroundTask == UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid) {
          print("UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier invalid")
          print("UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier beginBackgroundTask")
          backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { () -> Void in
             self.markAsDeliverChat(pathStr: pathStr, chatID: chatId)
             UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
             self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
           }
     }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

}


func markAsDeliverChat(pathStr: String, chatID: String) {           
        let FIREBASE_CHAT_URL = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
        let database = Database.database(url: FIREBASE_CHAT_URL).reference()
        let chatRef = database.child("Chat/\(pathStr)")
        let query = chatRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "id").queryEqual(toValue: chatID)
        print("FIREBASE_CHAT_URL = ", FIREBASE_CHAT_URL)
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapShot) in
            guard let value = snapShot.value as? NSDictionary else {
                print("chat id not found")
                return
            }
            print("not reaching here")
            /// HERE is all logic
        }
    }
```

Above function is working fine for foreground mode, but when i am in background mode, the code does not enter in  `query.observeSingleEvent`.

Comment: `observeSingleEvent` completes asynchronously which means you are ending your background task and you are calling the silent notification `completionHandler` before it has run, so you app is suspended. You don't need the `beginBackgroundTask`. You need to make sure you don't call the `completionHandler` until your operation is complete; ie call it in the closure for the `markAsDeliverChat`; this means that you will need to pass a closure to that function.

Comment: Also checked with completionHandler but 'observeSingleEvent' not called.

Comment: Edit your question to show your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

iOS (and Android for that matter) actively disallow such passive background traffic/connections from apps, as that'd harm battery life.  WhatsApp and other apps use [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns)/[FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to deliver updates to the user when the app is not active.

So you'd have a server listen to the database for updates, and then send a message though APNS/FCM to the device. A good example explaining this is in the documentation for Cloud Functions on [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

Also see:

- [Just how persistent are Firebase database observers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337765/just-how-persistent-are-firebase-database-observers)
- [Firebase database transaction when app is in background iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011182/firebase-database-transaction-when-app-is-in-background-ios)

Comment: I am using FCM with content-available: 1 in payload, so that app will awake. I am getting all the payload like PathString and chat node id to update Firebase Realtime Database to acknowledge otherside user.